# How to find out if a character in a string is an integer

Tags: c++, string, numbers

Let's say I want to look at the character at position 10 in a string s.

s.at(10);

What would be the easiest way to know if this is a number?

Answer (score 20):

Use [isdigit](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cctype/isdigit/)

```
std::string s("mystring is the best");
if ( isdigit(s.at(10)) ){
    //the char at position 10 is a digit
}
```

You will need

```
#include <ctype.h>
```

to ensure `isdigit` is available regardless of implementation of the standard library.

Comment: fails for the following digits: ४, ୬, ௧, ໙

Comment: @Bill Sure, but the example was based on the assumption that the requirement was for ascii digits. The page I linked to explained the solution if the programmer required locale specific digits and I can't second guess the programmers requirements.

Comment: I understand your assumptions, I just didn't see anything in the original question to justify them.

Answer (score 9):

The other answers assume you only care about the following characters: `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9`.  If you are writing software that might operate on locales that use other numeral systems, then you'll want to use the newer `std::isdigit` located in `<locale>`: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/locale/isdigit/

Then you could recognize the following digits as digits: `४, ੬, ൦, ௫, ๓, ໒`

Answer (score 5):

The following will tell you:

```
isdigit( s.at( 10 ) )
```

will resolve to 'true' if the character at position 10 is a digit.

You'll need to include < ctype >.

Comment: In C++, implementations may set up their headers such that one header includes another. `std::string` required `<string>` which may very well have brought in `<ctype>` _on your implementation_. That's coincidence; you can't rely on that.

Answer (score 4):

Another way is to check the ASCII value of that character

```
if ( s.at(10) >= '0' && s.at(10) <= '9' )
  // it's a digit
```

Comment: This fails for digits such as ४, ୬, ௧, ໙ .  std::isdigit is a better choice for real-world applications: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/locale/isdigit/

Answer (score 3):

Use [isdigit](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cctype/isdigit/):

```
if (isdigit(s.at(10)) {
    ...
}
```